# Webserver only launches from http://localhost:8000

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm running this hello world example:

https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/quickstart/#running-examples

```
$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.32s
     Running `C:\Users\m3\repos\Rocket\target\debug\hello_world.exe`
Configured for development.
    => address: localhost
    => port: 8000
    => log: normal
    => workers: 8
    => secret key: generated
    => limits: forms = 32KiB
    => keep-alive: 5s
    => read timeout: 5s
    => write timeout: 5s
    => tls: disabled
Mounting /:
    => GET / (hello)
Rocket has launched from http://localhost:8000
```

The code is available here:

https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/tree/v0.4/examples/hello_world

#### Problem

The problem is it only launches from `http://localhost:8000`. It doesn't work for `http://127.0.0.1:8000` or `http://192.168.1.250:8000`.

#### Question

How can I modify the code to make the server launch from `127.0.0.1` or the static IP address of the server i.e. `192.168.1.250`? I examined the code, but couldn't figure out how.

#### Didn't work

Modifying `Cargo.toml` [config](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.3/rocket/config/#rockettoml) and adding address and port:

```
[global]
address = "0.0.0.0"
port = 80
```

Comment: Check https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/configuration/ put the configuration in `Rocket.toml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick glance at the [documentation](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/configuration/) mention a file named rocket.toml

Try to put the configuration in a file named `Rocket.toml`

```
[global]
address = "0.0.0.0"
port = 80
```

or for IPv6 (which should accept IPv4 too)

```
[global]
address = "::"
port = 80
```

Comment: Just commenting here that this only works for IPv4. For IPv6 reachable servers, set `address` to `"::"`. The `"::"` value works for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: I have not tested the suggestion from @KasparPoland but it sounds reasonable